# If I leave and enter Taiwan on same day, does this restart my day count under a travel visa?

Tags: tourist-visas, taiwan, visa-runs

I often travel from Taiwan to China for short periods, and my last trip was to Shanghai just for the day. If my Taiwan visa has a 90-day limit per entry, did the day-trip reset the count?

Answer (score 5):

Yes it did. Unlike many countries, Taiwan doesn't Limit your stay to 90 days per 180-day period, nor does it forbid visa runs. A number of expats live in Taiwan without a visa.

(note: you don't have a Taiwan visa for 90 days; rather, you can stay in Taiwan without a visa for 90 days)

Also, if you're a British or Canadian citizen, you can extend your stay by another 90 days with the MFA. Thus, you'd be able to stay for up to 6 months in one stay

Comment: Can you confirm specifically that a trip **to mainland China** resets the clock?  In some contexts, Taiwan's government doesn't consider mainland China to be a different country.

Comment: @NateEldredge They have separate borders, which is what counts here. Same with Hong Kong and Macau

Comment: thank you, so just to confirm - a half-day trip (leaving and returning on same date) resets the 90-day count?

Comment: @Dale That (returning on the same day) may be a different question. To be safe, it would be a good idea to return the next day, even though returning on the same day may work fine. I'm not really sure I'm afraid