# What is Taiwan's stance on visa runs?

Tags: visas, taiwan, visa-runs, swedish-citizens

I am planning on going to Taiwan for close to 90 days, a period I am eligible for visa-free entry for. Would it be OK (or possible), for me to temporarily fly out of Taiwan just to get another 90 days, as necessary, e.g. do a [visa run](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travel_visa#Visa_run)?

If it makes any difference, the reason for my visit is to visit my Taiwanese wife, who will be there to give birth to our son. We otherwise live and work full time in Japan.

Comment: Generally I would think no country likes visa runs. If countries liked visa runs, they would have been giving long term visas. Visa runs defeat the purpose of the short term visas, visa free entry and VWP's durations. The fact that some _allow/tolerate/overlook_ it doesn't mean they like it.

Comment: @SheikPaul I can imagine some countries (especially young/disputed ones like Taiwan) might like it in comparison to the hassle that comes with issuing longer-term visas. Probably more so if it's a difference of like 10 days. Though I am only speculating.

Comment: So to clarify, you normally live in Japan, but your wife is in Taiwan, aned you need > 90 days for the birth?

Comment: @MarkMayo I'm planning to be there for close to, but less than 90 days, and then for all three of us to come back to Japan. The visa run would be in case we wanted to or had to stay a little bit longer than planned (for whatever reason). The reason why I'm using most of the 90 days is just to get some time for recovery and give my son a chance to catch his breath before we put him on a plane... and get some paperwork done, like registering a name in preparation for applying for a Swedish passport for him.

Answer (score 3):

In a long email correspondence with the Taiwanese authority in Japan, who were made aware of the full details of my situation, I received the following advice:

- If the stay is known to exceed 90 days, it is recommended to get a visa
- A visa run would reset the stay eligibility to 90 days from the day of re-entry

They never hinted on it being a problem.

Also see:

- [If I leave and enter Taiwan on same day, does this restart my day count under a travel visa?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/76251/45804)
- [Taiwan maximum stay rules with reentry](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/24749/45804)